# Create a view by day of week with the range of date list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation and i spend long day to figure out please help me

This is the table

```
5555    Alex    10:47   2013-11-09
6666    Joel    00:09   2013-11-10
6666    Joel    22:10   2013-11-11
5555    Alex    01:00   2013-11-11
```

Like this it will have a week of dates i need to create a view with all 7 days as a row 
assume

```
day1 date is 2013-11-09
day2 date is 2013-11-10
day3 date is 2013-11-11
```

I need this

```
Emplid Name   Day1    Day2     Day3   Day4   Day5 Day6 Day7
555    Alex   10.47   --       01.00  --     --   --   --
666    Joel   --      00.09    22.10  --     --   --   --
```

if anybody can give a good solution other than this that will be very helpful

Thanks

I am getting this error

> Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Comment: erm, what's your not so good solution?

Comment: Are we assured that all the dates will be within the same week?

Comment: The set of possible day values is a prerequisite? I mean, do you know which is the first day of the week and so on?

Comment: Yes I know the Start date and end date

Comment: Please edit your error message into your question; not into an answer.  If it's specific to @mucio's answer, not additional information about your base problem, indicate that fact when you make the edit.

Comment: tnx for your information

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: I have corrected the code and added a demo for the original problem, you have to split the rank and the max in two different queries, like I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like:

```
    SELECT Emplid,
           Name,
           max(day1) day1,
           max(day2) day2,
           max(day3) day3,
           max(day4) day4,
           max(day5) day5,
           max(day6) day6,
           max(day7) day7
      FROM (
              SELECT Emplid,
                     Name,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 1 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day1,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 2 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day2,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 3 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day3,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 4 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day4,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 5 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day5,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 6 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day6,
                     CASE WHEN rank() over(partition by Emplid, Name order by date) = 7 THEN time ELSE NULL END Day7
                FROM your_table
           ) t
  GROUP BY Emplid,
           Name
```

You can check this [demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab07f/8)

Comment: @aas please check now

Comment: HI @mucio thanks :) is working but i need to put aggregation function to get the sum of time  (SELECT FORMAT((sum(datediff(minute, 0, time)) / 60.0),'N2')) i tried is saying to group but i dont know where to group advice me thanks

Comment: And how to use more than one table is not allowing to add more than one table in select like if i want to add SELECT e.Emplid,
           e.Name,a.id

Comment: you need to do the sum of day1, day2 and so on. Outside the subquery. For the multiple tables the easiest thing is to figure out how to obtain a table/subquery similar to the one in your original question

Comment: I am doing this`(SELECT FORMAT((sum(datediff(minute, 0, max(Day1))) / 60.0),'N2')) Day1,` but i am getring this error `Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: If I am not using the MAX is working but why you used max on there please advice me

Comment: remove the max, my max is there to aggregate rows, if you run only the query t you will see what I mean. Just remove the max

Comment: Ya i got it otherwise cannot use group by. Thanks @mucio

Comment: Hi @muchio please check this demo in sql fiddle [link(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e67b/1) and check why Day2 is null there is value in day2.  which is in day3 should be in day2 and day4 should be in day3 please check

Comment: why? because of multiple table ?

Comment: @aas come one, please make the effort to giigke the difference between rank and dense_rank. Dense_rank is the function that gives you the results that you want, because doesn't leave empty ranks. But again google it to understand the differences